# MainPanel input not working in android SlidingPaneLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

thanks to all, Am using this fragments in SlidingPaneLayout, on opening the application, second fragment was the main and visible first, the issue is when i touch the inputs, it directly focused on the first fragment inputs which is behind the main frament.

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/rightpane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.example.incarnus_fragments.SearchReferralOutFragment"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/leftpane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        class="com.example.incarnus_fragments.PatientInputDetails"/>
```